# IntelliJ does not detect java classes from a different package

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ suddenly does not recognize classes from a different package and turns them red. Weirdly though, since those objects are there, I am having no issue compiling and running everything. Any idea what might be causing it and how can I rectify this?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of project is this? Maven, ant, etc?

Comment: Did you try: File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart ?

Comment: @Eranda It's a Maven Project

Comment: Try to execute mvn idea:idea using command line. Then re-open the project. Some times dependency resolving can be crashed in interllij idea.

Comment: Anything specific of just some of your classes?

Comment: @Eranda `mvn idea:idea` should **NOT** be used. It was last updated in 2008 and is totally outdated. IntelliJ has built-in support for maven.

Comment: @maba Idea is intelligent enough to make the necessary updates when you open.

Comment: @Eranda It shouldn't be used. Period.

Comment: I found out what the issue is, but still no solution to it. Maven is not able to import the dependencies for certain modules and on the right side, the maven projects are underlined in red and it says "Cannot reconnect". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you project compiles that must  mean you have your dependencies properly set in your POM.

Try showing the list of available intention actions for the class you see as red and check the import options or dependency suggestions.

Although this is probably a problem of caches. After invalidating cache as Rafael suggested, try reimporting your maven projects. And if you haven't already, tick the auto-import option.

If that stil doesn't work you can try checking out your code out of your version control repo or simply copying only your source code folders or cleaning your project and importing it again in IDEA.

Comment: I tried invalidating caches and restarting, deleted the project and made a different folder from the repository. Still nothing